# Kernel crash when Saving/Get ing big files

Tags: crash, save

I have been experiencing crashes in Mathematica 11.0.1 on a machine at work. I've tracked down the problem to when Mathematica is either using `Save[fileName]` or `Get[fileName]`, but sometimes the crash occurs a few minutes after loading a file. The files I am using are fairly big (350-650MB), which contain saved variables from before. The crashes seem to occur at random, i.e. sometimes the file is loaded properly and the script terminates but sometimes it crashes with everything being the same. I have checked the logs and each time there was a crash, I was the only one on the machine executing either mathematica or anything else.

What's weird is that on my laptop (Mathematica v.12) I haven't encountered any problem, and neither has my officemate (same Mathematica version as the server's).

Is there an option that could have been modfied on the server that could explain those problems? I do not have root access on the server.

Comment: You may want to look at using `DumpSave` instead.